# In Umbraco 7, how can i search for all members with a custom property?

Tags: c#, linq, umbraco, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco 7 (C#).

Is there an easy way/method to search for all members with a custom property?

I know that there is an easy way to search for all members by the username by using the method

```
GetByUsername(string username) : returns IMember
```

And also for searcing by Email:

```
GetByEmail(string email) : returns IMember
```

Do you know of such a way to search by a property?

I have tried using the method ".Where" like so:

```
GetService().GetAllMembers().Cast<IMember>().Where("permalink=SOMESTRING").ToArray();
```

Unfortunatly there is an error, since i can't use the .Where() method here.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could just use the build in function in MemberService.

From the doc:

```
Services.MemberService

.GetMembersByPropertyValue("city", "Horsens");
//Returns all Members, of any type, with a mathcing value in the property with the given property alias
```

http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management-v6/Services/MemberService